# How to switch zeros for blanks in a range in excel?

Tags: excel

I need to select a column from sheet1 and the selected column matches destination cell's row. I've got this code

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2;ROW();;;"Sheet1")):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(101;ROW();;;"Sheet1")))
```

but it selects blank values (empty cells) as zeros insted of empty cells!

I tried to fix it with something like

```
IF(
    (
        INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2;ROW();;;"Sheet1")):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(101;ROW();;;"Sheet1"))
    )=0;
    "";
    (INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2;ROW();;;"Sheet1")):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(101;ROW();;;"Sheet1"))))
```

which of course doesn't work because I'm trying to apply the condition to a range instead of a value.

Is there any way to select the range
 `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2;ROW();;;"Sheet1")):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(101;ROW();;;"Sheet1"))` picking 
the blanks as blanks instead of zeros?

Comment: Does that mean that you want the blank cells to go to the false part of the `IF`?

Comment: No. If a cell is blank, `INDIRECT` returns 0. I want to go back to blank, because I need blanks in my range, not zeros. If the condition is matched, then the selected value must be blank instead of zero (there are no zeros in the original range, so I don't have to worry about converting them too). If the condition is not matched, then there is no change: It just keeps the value from the selected range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? I have put your formula inside the `TRIM()` formula.

`=TRIM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2;ROW();;;"Sheet1")):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(101;ROW();;;"Sheet1"))))`

**Note**: `Trim()` will return a string. So if the cell is blank then you will get a blank but if the cell has a number then you will get the number as string

See this Example

[image]

Comment: Nope. I need numbers as numbers (I'm applying `correl` with the range as one of the two input parameters). But the number 0 as blank (only because `indirect` turns every empty cell into a zero, who knows why...)

Comment: Those are numbers only. the difference is that they are left aligned. If you want you can use them in calculations. For example. In D5 if you type `= D2 + 1`, you will get `2`

Comment: And the above formula does what you want. it shows blanks as blanks and not `0's`

Comment: In the end it turned out my problem using `CORREL` was not the blank->zero subtitutions in the range values, but something completely different (In fact `CORREL` *needs* the zeros, it doesn't accept blanks): I was importing decimals with `.` separator and default settings are `,` separator for decimals and `.` separator for thousands, hence the crazy values... But your solution seems to be alright and answers my question, so I marked it as accepted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I see you may not need an answer any more but I note that your original attempt will work - you **can** apply an IF to a range, i.e.

`=IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2;ROW();;;"Sheet1")):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(101;ROW();;;"Sheet1"))="";"";INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2;ROW();;;"Sheet1")):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(101;ROW();;;"Sheet1")))`

....but the INDIRECT/ADDRESS combination may not be required, you could return your original array with this formula

`=INDEX(Sheet1!$2:$101;0;ROW())`

and then just apply a simple IF function to that, i.e.

`=IF(INDEX(Sheet1!$2:$101;0;ROW())="";"",INDEX(Sheet1!$2:$101;0;ROW()))`

both of those will keep the numeric values numeric